# How to install Ubuntu to a hard drive without the installer process

Tags: boot, hard-drive

So for various reasons I can't boot off an install usb. So instead I have been taking the Hard drive out of my laptop and then writing to it with Universal USB installer. The result though is that I can boot up on my computer into an installer but I cant run it because it would install on the very HD im installing from.

How can I run the installer you normally get when you boot up onto the HD on windows?

Comment: You could run an Ubuntu live image in a virtual machine with USB access (under Windows) to install it to your hard drive, I suppose... though using a USB stick would be simpler. If you have a DVD drive, another good option would be to create an Ubuntu LiveDVD instead of USB

Comment: how would i direct the installation files to the hard drive though?

Comment: I misunderstood -- I didn't realize you only have one hard drive. In that case, the only way to use the entire drive as an installation target is to boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB or LiveDVD, either on your computer or someone else's computer.

Comment: You could also use [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) to install from within windows - not sure if this still works though.